# OSX Terminal - How To Write This Command Correctly To Import CSV Into MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv, terminal

I'm trying to import a TSV file into Mongodb.  However I'm not very good with Terminal, and the following command keeps failing.  Any advice?

```
/mongoimport --db webapp-dev --collection cities --type tsv --file ~/Desktop/cities.csv

Tue Nov 19 17:05:25.237 SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'Desktop'
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything right. But for some reason it treats it as a regular expression. How about trying to access the file from the same folder with mongoimport?

Answer (score 0):

`mongoimport` is an OS shell command, NOT a MongoDB shell command.
Start new OS shell and retry `mongoimport`.

Usually (for non root user) OS shell will prompt you with `user@host$` or simply `$`.

If `mongoimport` is in system `PATH` your command will be:

```
$ mongoimport --db webapp-dev --collection cities --type tsv --file ~/Desktop/cities.csv
```

If `mongoimport` is NOT in system `PATH` your command will be (full path):

```
$ /path/to/mongodb/bin/mongoimport --db webapp-dev --collection cities --type tsv --file ~/Desktop/cities.csv
```